# MySQL grouping with detail

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this...

```
user_id, match_id, points_won
1          14         10
1          8          12
1          12         80
2          8          10
3          14         20
3          2          25
```

I want to write a MYSQL script that pulls back the most points a user has won in a single match and includes the match_id in the results - in other words...

```
user_id, match_id, max_points_won
1          12          80
2          8           10
3          2           25
```

Of course if I didn't need the match_id I could just do...

```
select user_id, max(points_won)
from table
group by user_id
```

But as soon as I add match_id to the "select" and "group by" I have a row for every match, and if I only add the match_id to the "select" (and not the "group by") then it won't correctly relate to the points_won.

Ideally I don't want to do the following either because it doesn't feel particularly safe (e.g. if the user has won the same amount of points on multiple matches)...

```
SELECT t.user_id, max(t.points_won) max_points_won
, (select t2.match_id 
   from table t2 
   where t2.user_id = t.user_id 
   and t2.points_won = max_points_won) as 'match_of_points_maximum'
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Are there any more elegant options for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is harder than it needs to be in MySQL.  One method is a bit of a hack but it works in most circumstances.  That is the `group_concat()`/`substring_index()` trick:

```
select user_id, max(points_won),
       substring_index(group_concat(match_id order by points_won desc), ',', 1) 
from table
group by user_id;
```

The `group_concat()` concatenates together all the `match_id`s, ordered by the points descending.  The `substring_index()` then takes the first one.

Two important caveats:

- The resulting expression has a type of string, regardless of the internal type.
- The `group_concat()` uses an internal buffer, whose length -- by default -- is 1,024 characters.  This default length can be changed.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - hack or not, that is actually exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query:

```
select user_id, max(points_won) 
from table
group by user_id
```

as a derived table. Joining this to the original table gets you what you want:

```
select t1.user_id, t1.match_id, t2.max_points_won 
from table as t1
join (
    select user_id, max(points_won) as max_points_won
    from table
    group by user_id
) as t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.points_won = t2.max_points_won
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgos - this is a perfectly good solution but I am (perhaps unnecessarily) nervous about joining back to points_won from the maximum (e.g. if there's multiple records on the same maximum points)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** only for postgresql, sql-server, oracle

You could use row_number :

```
SELECT USER_ID, MATCH_ID, POINTS_WON
FROM
(
    SELECT user_id, match_id, points_won, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by points_won desc) rn
    from table
) q
where q.rn = 1
```

For a similar function, have a look at Gordon Linoff's answer or at this [article](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/).

In your example, you partition your set of result per user then you order by points_won desc to obtain highest winning point first.

Comment: sorry devoh - but I get a "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version" when running this - perhaps a valid solution for other versions though of course

Comment: My bad. I didn't know that mysql doesn't support row_number() like Sql-Server, Oracle or Postgre.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can optimize your query by add limit 1 in the inner query.

```
SELECT t.user_id, max(t.points_won) max_points_won
, (select t2.match_id 
   from table t2 
   where t2.user_id = t.user_id 
   and t2.points_won = max_points_won limit 1) as 'match_of_points_maximum'
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.user_id
```

Comment: thanks algojava - the only problem is that I think my original example query might have been flawed - I get an "Reference 'max_points_won' not supported (reference to group function)" error when running this